# Problem with table creation through Models Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I am working on a Hotel site (educational project) on Django. I have BookingForm(ModelsForm) and respectively Booking(models.Model). Although form is working correctly (I debugged, data is valid), my form doesn't create Booking table in default Django database sqllite3, it's never appeared in admin panel.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

import datetime

from django.db.models import EmailField
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator, RegexValidator

ROOM_TYPES = [
    ('1', "Single - 200"),
    ('2', "Double - 350"),
    ('3', "Twin - 350"),
    ('4', "Double-Double - 600"),
    ('5', "King Room - 450"),
    ('6', "Luxury - 800")
]
GUESTS_NUMBER = [
    ('1', "1 person. Single comfort room"),
    ('2', "2 people. Recommended Double, Twin or King room"),
    ('3', "3 people. Double-Double or Luxury will match your needs"),
    ('4', "4 people. Double-Double or Luxury will match your needs"),
    ('5', "5 people. Our Luxury room is for you!")
]
STAT = [
    ('0', "Waits for payment"),
    ('1', "Paid")
]


class Booking(models.Model):
    check_in = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    check_out = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    room_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=ROOM_TYPES, default=2)
    guests_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=GUESTS_NUMBER, default=2)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)
    email = EmailField(max_length=254, blank=False, validators=[EmailValidator()])
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=STAT, default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.surname
```

forms.py

```
from app.models import Booking
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django_flatpickr.widgets import DatePickerInput


class BookingForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ["check_in", "check_out", "room_type", "guests_number", "name", "surname", "phone", "email", ]
        widgets = {
            "check_in": DatePickerInput(),
            "check_out": DatePickerInput(),
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from app.forms import BookingForm


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    form = BookingForm()
    return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})


def book(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_booking = form.save()
            return HttpResponse('form had gone')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('bad')
    else:
        return render(request, "index.html", {'form': BookingForm()})
```

index.html -> section booking

```
<section class="page-section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Ready to book?</h2>
            <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Select all necessaries, we'll take care of your comfort</h3>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action={% url 'booking_confirmation' %} class="booking-form">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="calendar-container">
                  <div class="date-fields">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="check_in">Check-in Date:</label>
                      <input type="text" id="check_in" name="check_in" readonly class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="check_out">Check-out Date:</label>
                      <input type="text" id="check_out" name="check_out" readonly class="form-control">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="room_type">Room Type:</label>
                    <select id="room_type" name="room_type" required class="form-control">
                      <option value="1">1 person. Single comfort room</option>
                      <option value="2">2 people. Recommended Double, Twin or King room</option>
                      <option value="3">3 people. Double-Double or Luxury will match your needs</option>
                      <option value="4">4 people. Double-Double or Luxury will match your needs</option>
                      <option value="5">5 people. Our Luxury room is for you!</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="guests_number">Number of people:</label>
                  <select id="guests_number" name="guests_number" required class="form-control">
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="phone">Mobile Phone:</label>
                  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" required class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email:</label>
                  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>

                    <button style="opacity: 1!important;" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" id="submitButton" type="submit">Send Message</button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>


<!-- JS for flatpickr -->
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
        <script>
        const checkInField = document.getElementById('check_in');
        const checkOutField = document.getElementById('check_out');

        flatpickr("#check_in", {
          minDate: "today",
          dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
          onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            if (selectedDates.length > 0) {
              const checkInDate = selectedDates[0];
              const adjustedCheckInDate = new Date(checkInDate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
              checkInField.value = adjustedCheckInDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
              flatpickr("#check_out", {
                minDate: adjustedCheckInDate,
                dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
                onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                  if (selectedDates.length > 0) {
                    const checkOutDate = selectedDates[0];
                    const adjustedCheckOutDate = new Date(checkOutDate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                    checkOutField.value = adjustedCheckOutDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
                  } else {
                    checkOutField.value = '';
                  }
                }
              });
            } else {
              checkInField.value = '';
              checkOutField.value = '';
            }
          }
        });
        </script>
```

Firstly, error was with data validity, I fixed it. I had to refuse using PhoneNumberField to regex validation, and form sending is works, so I am afraid to break this fragile harmony))  Now, debug goes into block "form.isvalid():", passes "newbooking = form.save()" and returns positive http response. So I have no ideas why it successfully passes second step, but does not create model (table). Maybe, there are configurations to sqllite in Django ....IDK

*I want my form to look the same way like in index.html, and model had all its fields, but table was created and filled by post request (form). And if you know how to avoid "return HttpResponse()" after "form.is*_valid()", please, share this info too. I want to redirect on success page or make a message, but than I get error required to  use HttpResponse.

Please, help....I am desperate. I need any fresh and preferably correct and helpful ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, problem was extremely stupid - I forgot to register Booking model in admin.py . Here is a code, if it is useful

```
 from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Booking

admin.site.register(Booking)
```

Comment: Indentation issue in line 1.